# How to change header for partial view in angular 2?

Tags: angular, navbar

I am using two navbar in my application one is common for all pages and second one is only for particular page.How can i call second one only for particular view only.Please explain with example.

Comment: In main component set variable e.g. headerName and display it. When u change view by this particular page let change headerName.

Comment: can u please give some more clarification with example/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I solved it on my way. I used Observer pattern creating am interface, registering my component on the sender of the event that knew when my header should change.